# Can I make IDEA's Gradle auto-import watch an arbitrary properties file?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a properties file that I am loading in my `build.gradle` file like so:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("myFile.properties"))
```

I have found that if I enable Intellij IDEA's Gradle auto-import*, IDEA auto-imports my Gradle project if I make a change to `build.gradle`, but not if I make a change to `myFile.properties`.

Is there any way that I can make it so that auto-import will detect a change to `myFile.properties` and then trigger an import?

---

* This setting can be enabled via Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle, then checking the box "Use auto-import"

Comment: No, related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173056.